# how to allow access to folders only for localhost in apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I want to allow access to these folders only for localhost

.htaccess file not working correctly

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Here is the
[error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkgmt.png)

Comment: You may also want to allow the `ipv6` localhost address, `Allow from fe80::1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that way :

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

Comment: it works ! but i have some PHP scripts to execute by AJAX , any solution ?